# What is the difference between "&" and "and" in writing?

Tags: conjunctions, ampersand

Can I use either whenever I want to use an *and*?

For example,

> - I like to play and sing
> - I like to play & sing
>
> ---
>
> - We will walk and she will run.
> - We will walk & she will run.

Comment: I have wondered about the same thing I know they use & for posters signs or stuff like that while and is used for sentences and writing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The choice as to which to use comes down to the degree of formality of your text, and possibly also how much space you have available (e.g. when putting together a PowerPoint slide).

In general, using *&* implies a much more informal tone than *and*.

You will never be criticized for using *and*, whereas you run the risk of disapproval if you use *&* in anything but informal notes, tweets and the like.

Comment: "&" is also often used in company names or titles, i.e. *Barnes & Noble*. In that case it's most likely an aesthetic choice more than anything (plus it shortens a name that is already likely to be long).

Comment: @txteclipse - Quite right. Good point.

Comment: Conversely, they have different formal meanings in specific contexts. For example two screenwriters who worked as a team would be credited as "A & B", while a film that had two screenwriters who didn't work as a team would be listed as "A and B". Thus also possible to have "A & B and C" in the credits.

Comment: This is not about degree of formality at all.

Answer (score 2):

Ampersand (&) is rare in formal written English, although in informal e-mails, texts etc. it's usually noticed.

Reference : [When Can You Use It?](http://www.brighthub.com/multimedia/publishing/articles/80530.aspx)